# Disable elasticsearch default password in kubernetes

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

how can I disable secret creating for elasticsearch? I'm using deployment with Kind: ElasticSearch and I want to use my own password but elastic is still recreating k8s password like elastic: password with name xyz-elastic-user. Is it possible to disable it? I found https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/main/elasticsearch/values.yaml#L60 but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

you can set custom password through `env` if you do not want to use the auto-generated one.

```
extraEnvs:
  - name: ELASTIC_PASSWORD
    value: my-passs
```

[extraEnvs](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/main/elasticsearch/values.yaml#L47)

make sure to set `secret` false.

```
secret:
  enabled: false
```